# Show that the logic $ \ \forall x \exists y \ P(x,y) \ $ is not logically equivalent to $ \ \exists x \forall y \ P(x,y) \ $

Tags: logic

Show that the logic $ \ \forall x \exists y \ P(x,y) \ $ is not logically equivalent to $ \ \exists x \forall y \ P(x,y) \ $  in the **domain** $ \ \{-1,0,1 \} \ $ by giving a **counter example** .

**Answer:**

Let

$ x=\{0,1 \} \\ y=\{-1,0 ,1 \} \ $

Let $ P(x,y) \ $ be the property such that $ \ x \geq y \ $

Then , $ \forall x \exists y \ P(x,y) \ $ is true.

But, $ \ \exists x \forall y \ P(x,y) \ $ is False. Because for $ x=0 \ $ , we have $ \ 0 \ngeqslant y=1 \ $.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

Comment: No, both $x$ and $y$ must come from the same domain of discourse, which is $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: But if the property does not hold in a sub-domain , then it will not be true in the domain. Is not it true ?

Comment: An existential statement may fail in a sub-domain but "hold true" in a larger domain.  E.g. a square root may fail to exist in the real numbers but exist in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't just assign $x$ and $y$ to some subset of your domain - they're both elements of the domain, not subsets. Your property also doesn't work - both statements are true in this domain.

Define $P(x, y)$ to be the property that $x + y = 0$.

Then $\forall x \exists y P(x, y)$ is true, since:

- If $x = -1$, then we can take $y = 1$ to get $-1 + 1 = 0$.
- If $x = 0$, then we can take $y = 0$ to get $0 + 0 = 0$.
- If $x = 1$, then we can take $y = -1$ to get $1 + (-1) = 0$.

On the other hand, $\exists x \forall y P(x, y)$ is false, since otherwise we would have:
$$
x + (-1) = x + 0 = x + 1 \iff -1 = 0 = 1
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Can you give an example showing that $ \exists x \forall y \ P(x,y) \ $ is not logically equivalent to $ \exists y \forall x \ P(x,y) \ $  ?

Comment: Just find an anti-symmetric property where $P(x, y) \neq P(y, x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exist a real number $a$ such that $n<a$, for example $a = n+1.$ However, there is not a real number $a$ such that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n<a$, because $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded.

Comment: In the domain $ \{-1,0,1 \} \ $.

Comment: Your work is incorrect. Because $x=1 \geq y$, for all $y$. So you are not proving what is required.

Comment: The counterexample I gave you works fine.

Comment: But your domain is the set of natural number

Comment: When construction counterexamples, you can choose any domain that works.

Comment: @HeMan Unrestricting the domain of the quantifiers leads to a strictly stronger claim, that $\forall x \exists y Pxy = \exists y \forall x Pxy$ over a domain of $\mathbb N$.  Showing a counter example to a stronger claim doesn't establish that the weaker claim in the question is false.